# Monitoring spring boot cache metrics with Prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cache, micrometer

I am trying to use prometheus to monitor some cache metrics from spring-boot.  The cache is created with `@Cacheable` and my configuration is as follows:

```
management.endpoints:
  web.exposure.include: "*"
  metrics.enabled: true
  prometheus.enabled: true
management.metrics:
  export.prometheus.enabled: true
  cache.instrument: true
```

My cache is created with a simple `@Cacheable('mycache')` - I have no other cache code or setup.  **I'm also NOT using any specific cache provided just the built in one.**

I do see my cache in the `/actuator/caches/` list, but no detailed in either the `/metrics` or `/prometheus` endpoints.

My expectation was that some cache metrics would be published to both the `/actuator/metrics` and `/actuator/prometheus` endpoints.

I saw some notes about manually needing to register the cache, but I couldn't get that working either (nor am I sure it really pertains).  When attempting to do this the issue is that I cannot autowire in the `CacheMetricsRegistrar` bean.  It's not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a Micrometer binder for the built in hashmap based cache. See https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/cache for the implementation created out of the box.

Those implementation keep track of their hit/miss counts themselves. Since nothing is tracking the hashmap isn't tracking metrics, there are none available to surface.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I would need to use another cache implementation (ehcache for example) to see any metrics?

Comment: Yes. I would recommend Caffeine

Answer (score 2):

It seems you got your property wrong, it should be  **endpoint** you have and extra **s**

your property should be `management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled`

you can refer all actuators properties here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#actuator-properties

**Edit:**
Endpoint property mentioned is as per **Spring boot 2.2**

**Edit 2**

While reading more about actuator cache, on this  [URL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-cache) on #6.3.5. Cache Metrics, I found

> Only caches that are available on startup are bound to the registry.
>   For caches created on-the-fly or programmatically after the startup
>   phase, an explicit registration is required. A **CacheMetricsRegistrar**
>   bean is made available to make that process easier.

I further explored **CacheMetricsRegistrar** and at this [URL](https://medium.com/@iliamsharipov_56660/spring-boot-actuator-for-concurrentmapcache-2c7f0d290934), I found an example, which I implemented in my actuator sample project.

now I can see books cache details in Prometheus URL of application something like below

```
# TYPE cache_gets_total counter
cache_gets_total{cache="books",cacheManager="cacheManager",name="books",result="hit",} 4.0
cache_gets_total{cache="books",cacheManager="cacheManager",name="books",result="miss",} 2.0
```

Comment: Even with the s the endpoints are being created properly, the issue is the cache metrics arent being shown in the prometheus endpoint.

Comment: which spring boot version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.0

Comment: Also, I'm not using any specific cache implementation, just the default spring concurrent map.

Comment: ok you need to add more info in question, what URL you are accessing and what is expectation and some code

Comment: Sure, I added some more details to the OP.

Comment: can you refer to my actuator sample and explain  https://github.com/KoolShailesh/actuator-service-example

Comment: Yes, I ran your example, same issue as mine.  The actuator/metrics and actuator/prometheus endpoint have no information about the books cache.  Things like # of its, misses and size should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

As *checketts* said, there are no metrics registered by micrometer for the simple implementation backed by a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

The cache libraries supporting metrics in Spring Boot are also listed there : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-cache.

It also says

> Only caches that are configured on startup are bound to the registry.

It means that you **must declare** the caches you want to monitor at startup, like this :

```
spring.cache.cache-names=books
```

You'll find this property in the application.properties, see : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-cache.

If you want to test, add for example [Caffeine](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-caching-provider-caffeine) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then if the prometheus endpoint is activated, you'll see this for example :

```
# TYPE cache_size gauge
cache_size{cache="books",cacheManager="cacheManager",name="books",} 2.0
```

---

Code tested with Spring Boot 2.4