# See cache application consumption into New Relic

Tags: java, newrelic

We have cache consumption problems in an application monitored by New Relic.
How can I see the memory consumption by filtering for the cache part?

Comment: What technology are you using for caching ?

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich CacheManager of org.springframework.cache

Comment: You need to use the combination of these two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475039/monitoring-spring-boot-cache-metrics-with-prometheus and https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/how-to-monitor-spring-boot-applications-using-micrometer-metrics